# Foreach loop insert same data multiple time

Tags: php, ajax, foreach, nested-loops

Nested foreach loop has ruined my day. Data is inserted mutliple times (same value is inserted based on how many nested menu checked) and nested value is stored in every row though they are not parent.

I think **problem is caused by nested foreach loop**

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['heading']) && !empty($_POST['content']) && !empty($_POST['keytag']) && !empty($_POST['date'])){
        $heading=$_POST['heading'];
        $content=$_POST['content'];
        $keytag=$_POST['keytag'];
        $date=$_POST['date'];
        $query = '';
        $msg = '';

        $data = explode("," ,$_POST["navid"]);
        $subdata = explode("," ,$_POST["subnavid"]);
            foreach ($data AS $key => $menu){
                foreach($subdata AS $k => $submenu){

                    //If Image is browsed 
                    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
                        $query = $con->prepare('INSERT into news(heading, cat_id, subcat_id, content, keytag, date, img) VALUES(:heading, :cat_id, :subcat_id, :content, :keytag, :date, :new_img)');
                        $query->bindParam(':new_img',$new_img);
                    }

                    //If Image isnot browsed 

                    if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){
                        $query = $con->prepare('INSERT into news(heading, cat_id, subcat_id, content, keytag, date) VALUES(:heading, :cat_id, :subcat_id, :content, :keytag, :date)');
                    }
                    if(empty($submenu)){
                       $submenu = null;
                    }
                    $query->bindParam(':heading', $heading);
                    $query->bindParam(':subcat_id', $submenu);
                    $query->bindParam(':cat_id', $menu);
                    $query->bindParam(':content', $content);
                    $query->bindParam(':keytag', $keytag);
                    $query->bindParam(':date', $date);

                    if($query->execute()){
                        $msg="Successfully Inserted";
                    };
                }
            }
            echo $msg;
        }
```

}
        ?>

Here is problem

[image]

Let me explain in brief. Site has three menus : `News`, `Views`, `Art`. Among them **only News menu has submenu**. If News' `submenu` and `Views/Art` is **checked at once**, by default `Views/Art` column also stores `submenu` value, but **in real View/Art has not submenu**, it **is storing News submenu value**.

**It should be**

[image]
Here is html

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="2">News
    <ul>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu[][menusub]" value="2">Politics
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu[][menusub]" value="3">Social
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu[][menusub]" value="4">Economy
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="12">Views                                 
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="13">ART                               
</li>
```

Data is passed through ajax as below

```
    $(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var navid = [];
        $("input[name='menu[]']:checked").each(function(){
            navid.push(this.value);
        });
        var subnavid = [];
        $("input[name='menu[][menusub][]']:checked").each(function(){
            subnavid.push(this.value);
        });
        if (navid.length === 0){ //tell you if the array is empty
            alert("Please Select atleast one checkbox");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            formData.append('navid', navid);
            formData.append('subnavid', subnavid);
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);

                        }
        });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out `$subdata = explode("," ,$_POST["subnavid"]);` from first `foreach` loop and you should be good to go.

Because with each parent loop, it extracts the `$_POST["subnavid"]` and the child loop will start from 1st member of array.

```
$subdata = explode("," ,$_POST["subnavid"]); // This is the change required.
foreach ($data AS $key => $menu){
   foreach($subdata AS $k => $submenu){
   ......
   ......
   }
}
```

Also change `$key` variable. Because its the same. So it might be getting overlapped with each loop.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but doesn't work. I think It's my weakness that I couldn't explain my problem in brief. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Notice the lines at bottom.

Comment: it is really annoying, still it doesn't work. I think problem is in storing value in variable. I'm storing `$heading=$_POST['heading']` But I think it should be `$heading=$_POST['heading'][$key]` Or `$heading=$_POST['heading'][$k]`. I tried it, doesn't work, Please see updated question, I've added `code` how I `value` stored, is it fine ? Your cooperation and help is highly appreciated brother.

Comment: mate, can you post what `$_POST["subnavid"]` has?

Comment: sorry for late, I was trying other options. `$_POST["subnavid"]` contains nested menu's value. I test using echo, it echo accurate value of checked nested element. Please see my updated ajax code. I forgot to add in previous post